# Changing value of a cell to trigger a macro

Tags: vba, excel

As the title suggests, I want a specific macro (PopulateCalculatorWithWeekChosen) to run whenever a user changes the value in the 'Summary' worksheet, cell H10.

I found the below question and answer and tried it but it doesn't seem to trigger it. Did I understand correctly that I put the code below...

[Trigger event when select from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339568/microsoft-excel-vba-trigger-event-when-select-from-dropdown)

```
Sub PopulateCalculatorWithWeekChosen()

If Target.Address = "$H$10" Then
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With
```

[the rest of the code in the PopulateCalculatorWithWeekChosen macro]

```
    With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End If
End Sub
```

...in the right place?
It doesn't seem to do anything. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've defined a macro and the question/answer you reference is using the `Worksheet_Change` event. In your VBA code, you should have Worksheet object which has a Change event. An event is just a function that is triggered when a specific thing happens.
In this case, the function `Worksheet_Change` triggers whenever the worksheet is modified. You should have something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$H$10" Then

      With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      End With

      With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      End With

    End If

End Sub
```

When you modify the worksheet, Excel will automatically call this function and tell you which cells were modified by providing that information in the `Target` parameter.

Comment: Thanks; can you explain what this is? (ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: Everything in the parenthesis is describing the parameters passed to the function. In this case, we have one parameter named Target. It's being passed by value (as opposed to by reference... if this makes no sense to you, don't worry about it, it's not all that important in the grand scheme of things). And it is of type Range. So when you modify the worksheet, Excel will call this function in the background. When it calls the function it provides useful information that can be used inside the function; the useful information being the range of cells modified.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I need to move the original code from a module to the Summary sheet? I did try that with a test MsgBox popping up in the middle of the above code's With statements and it worked. However, it's still not running my macro code, will play around with it.