# can you call a macro when selecting a value from a dropdown list?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with a dropdown list (AH,AR, CH etc).  Dependent on the value selected in the drop down the values on the sheet change which are a series of vlookups.
Some of these return blank rows and i have a macro that hides the rows if they are blank.

Is there a way that i can assisgn the macro to the drop down so that the macro is called on click.

Comment: Yes, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339568/trigger-event-when-select-from-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

You need to access that particular worksheet module, which you can do by right clicking on the sheet name and selecting **view code**. At this point you need to use a `Worksheet_Change` sub something like below, which will run code when the value of cell `A1` is changed

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "DropdownValue1"
               'do something
            Case "DropdownValue2"
                'do something else
        End Select 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It wont work Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet10").Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "AH" Then
       HideRows
    ElseIf Target.Value = "AR" Then
        HideRows
    ElseIf Target.Value = "BI" Then
      HideRows
    End If
    ElseIf Target.Value = "CH" Then
      HideRows
    End If
    ElseIf Target.Value = "CHL" Then
      HideRows
    End If
    ElseIf Target.Value = "CL" Then
      HideRows
    End If
    ElseIf Target.Value = "CN" Then
      HideRows
    End If
End If
End Sub

Comment: i still am unable to get this work what could i be doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can assign macros to the [Worksheet.Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event and add a condition that runs a specific macro based on the value.

For example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 

If Not Intersect(Target, Thisworkbook.Sheets("WorksheetName").Range("AH")) Is Nothing 
    If Target.Value = "DropdownValue1" Then
        Macro1
    Elseif Target.Value = "DropdownValue2" Then
        Macro2
    Elseif Target.Value = "DropdownValue3" Then
        Macro3
    End if
End if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify below code:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E1")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("E1")
            Case "Insert Blank rows": Macro1
            Case "Hide All Sheets": Macro2
            Case "Convert to Date": Macro3
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Ref: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4421-excel-run-macro-from-drop-down-list.html