# Call the sub routine in vba automatically when a cell selection has changed?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, drop-down-menu, selectionchanged

Can this formula still be modified?

1. I've been trying to compare three drop-down lists that shows either "Yes" or "No". However, whenever I make changes in excel it will not automatically activate or call the sub routine even if I tried to call the specific sub name.
2. Can you help me out with this (Note: I've even made my If Then Else Statement that long because of the string parameter that seems to be case sensitive.)

   ```
   Sub discountCheck()
   Sheets("Data - Discount").Select
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim xrow As Integer, yrow As Integer, zrow As Integer
   Dim aa As String, bb As String, cc As String
   xrow = 2
   yrow = 2
   zrow = 2
   For i = 1 To 4
   aa = Cells(xrow, 8).Value
   bb = Cells(yrow, 9).Value
   cc = Cells(zrow, 10).Value
   ' Yes / Yes / No
   If aa = "Yes" And bb = "Yes" And cc = "No" Then
   MsgBox ("Invalid discount placement! Check Invoice #: " & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)
   Exit Sub
   Else
     ' Yes / yes / No
     If aa = "Yes" And bb = "yes" And cc = "No" Then
     MsgBox ("Invalid discount placement! Check Invoice #: " & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)
     Exit Sub
     Else
       ' yes / Yes / No
       If aa = "yes" And bb = "Yes" And cc = "No" Then
       MsgBox ("Invalid discount placement! Check Invoice #: " & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)
       Exit Sub
       Else
       ' Yes / No / Yes
       If aa = "Yes" And bb = "No" And cc = "Yes" Then
       MsgBox ("Invalid discount placement! Check Invoice #: " & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)
       Exit Sub
       Else
           ' Yes / No / yes
           If aa = "Yes" And bb = "No" And cc = "yes" Then
           MsgBox ("Invalid discount placement! Check Invoice #: " & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)
           Exit Sub
           Else
               ' yes / No / Yes
               If aa = "yes" And bb = "No" And cc = "Yes" Then
               MsgBox ("Invalid discount placement! Check Invoice #: " & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)
               Exit Sub
               Else
                   ' no / Yes / Yes
                   If aa = "No" And bb = "Yes" And cc = "Yes" Then
                   MsgBox ("Invalid discount placement! Check Invoice #: " & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)
                   Exit Sub
                   Else
                       ' no / Yes / yes
                       If aa = "No" And bb = "Yes" And cc = "yes" Then
                       MsgBox ("Invalid discount placement! Check Invoice #: " & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)
                       Exit Sub
                       Else
                           ' no / yes / Yes
                           If aa = "No" And bb = "yes" And cc = "Yes" Then
                           MsgBox ("Invalid discount placement! Check Invoice #: " & Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)
                           Exit Sub
                           End If
                       End If
                   End If
               End If
           End If
       End If
   End If
   End If
   End If  
   xrow = xrow + 1
   yrow = yrow + 1
   zrow = zrow + 1
   Next i
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339568/trigger-event-when-select-from-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Reference [How to run macro when cell value changes in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4423-excel-run-macro-on-cell-change.html)

The idea is to make use of the cell `Change` event.

Example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Call Mymacro
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply. Really appreciate the answer suchislife