# Excel multi sheet value fetch

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In an Excel file I have 2 sheets.

In Sheet 2 i have some exchange rates in 2 columns

[image]

In Sheet 1 I want to choose the region from a dropdown and automatically, the cells containing prices are automatically calculated to that exchange rate.

So far, I have only managed to create a dropdown list using Data Validation.

I tried to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339568/trigger-event-when-select-from-dropdown) answer but im lost.

Am I on the right path for this?

Comment: Have you tried using VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH?

Comment: Would you provide a sample of the content for Sheet1 and what do you mean by: *"the cells containing prices are automatically calculated to that exchange rate"*. Thanks

Comment: Something like `=XLOOKUP(<drop-down cell>,<range containing Euro, UK, USA>,<range containing 1, 0.98, 0.95>)` will return the exchange rate.